# StableBaselines3 PPO Cannot learn anything

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

Hey I had a problem with my RL environment so I stripped it down to the smallest thing possible but PPO is still unable to learn the optimal action.
My Environment looks like this:

```
from typing import Any

import gymnasium as gym
import numpy as np
from gymnasium.core import ObsType, ActType

from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import BaseCallback


class LoggingCallback(BaseCallback):
    def __init__(self, verbose=0):
        super().__init__(verbose)
        self.infos = []

    def _on_step(self) -> bool:
        self.infos.append(self.locals["infos"][0])
        return True

    def __call__(self, locals_, globals_):
        self.locals = locals_
        self.globals = globals_
        self._on_step()


class Dummy(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self):

        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(1,),dtype=np.float32)
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=-1, high=1, shape=(1,), dtype=np.float32)

        self.state = 0.5
        self.counter = 0

    def reset(self, seed: int | None = None, options: dict[str, Any] | None = None, ) -> tuple[ObsType, dict[str, Any]]:
        super().reset(seed=seed)

        episode = 0
        self.counter = 0

        self.state = 0.5

        observation = np.array([self.state], dtype=np.float32)
        return observation, {}

    def step(self, action: ActType) -> tuple[ObsType, float, bool, bool, dict]:
        self.state += action[0] * 0.1

        observation = np.array([self.state], dtype=np.float32)
        reward = self.state
        terminated = self.counter > 100
        truncated = False
        self.counter += 1

        info = {"observation": observation, "action": action, "reward": reward}

        return observation, reward, terminated, truncated, info
```

Any my training code is:

```
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy
from src.environment.dummy import Dummy, LoggingCallback

env = Dummy()
model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env)
model.learn(total_timesteps=1000)
trained_callback = LoggingCallback()
trained_accumulated_reward, trained_std_reward = evaluate_policy(model, env, n_eval_episodes=1, callback=trained_callback)
print([el["action"] for el in trained_callback.infos])
```

And the actions taken are basically always around 0.15.
The relation between observation, action and reward is literally linear, why does PPO not learn to take the action 1 all the time?